# Let Unity show StyleCop errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stylecop, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a project which is developed with Unity3D. Now I want to add StyleCop to this project.

I have added [this awesome package](https://github.com/tertle/com.bovinelabs.analyzers) which shows the warnings already in VisualStudio (this is a great benefit over StyleCop Classic). But now I want to see the warnings in Unity and let the build fail. To let the build fail if there are any warnings, I have already added a `csc.rsp` file with `-warnaserror+`, but unfortunately, I don't have any warnings in Unity.

**Is it possible to get the StyleCop-warnings to the Unity-Editor?**

Unity-Version 2019.3.0b7 if that matters.

Edit: Another view of the same issue would be:

*How to install an analyzer to roslyn?*

Unfortunately I the options to install a roslyn analyzer seem to be to install it as nuget package or as Visual Studio extension. But since both ways integrate the errors into Visual Studio, I need another way to add an analyzer to roslyn, which lets the compiler issue errors which then get displayed in Unity3D.

Edit2: To be absolutely clear: I already can do `UnityEngine.Debug.LogError` and print every StyleCop error to the UnityConsole. But I want StyleCop to be integrated in the compilation pipeline of unity. So that I cannot press play anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure you can.

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#manually-configure-rule-severity)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you don't mind to write some little pieces of code.

- Unity has an [editor log file](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/LogFiles.html), it records every warning during your build. Like this:

  > Assets/SomeScript.cs(134,33): warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.Random.RandomRange(float, float)` is obsolete: Use `Random.Range` instead.
- Unity has a callback [IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild.html) , which has the following description:

  > Implement this interface to receive a callback before the
  >   build is started.

  You can start to monitor the log changes from then on.
- Unity also has a callback when a build is end, by adding a [PostProcessBuildAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html) to a specific function. Here is the description:

  > Add this attribute to a method to get a notification just after building the player.

  **[Update]**
- Now you've recorded if there are warnings in last build, you can make a flag in memory or in file system, then you add few lines of code to check this flag, if it's true then stop the playing by using `EditorApplication.ExitPlaymode()`

Comment: Your last assumption is not complete. Yes I want to fail my CI build, but this is what I already can. The question aims into the UnityEditor direction. I want, that the application will not play anymore.

Comment: Okay, this seems like a workaround, but it'll probably work. Do you have any thoughts on the second way: Can I install a roslyn analyzer into the compiler which resides under `Editor\Data\Tools\Roslyn\ ` and then turn the analyzer warnings into compiler errors with `-warnaserror+` in the `csc.rsp`?